# Relative links automatically gain the session ID

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session, storage

> Because the session ID is inserted in the current URL, relative links also automatically  gain the session ID. In other words, if the user is currently stationed on Page1.aspx and clicks a relative link to Page2.aspx, the relative link includes the current session ID as part of the URL.  The only real limitation of cookieless state is that you cannot use absolute links, because they will not contain the session ID.

I don’t understand why relative links are able to gain session ID, but not absolute links?

Thank you

Comment: What is the source of this quote?

Comment: Pro ASP>NET 3.5 in C# 2008 by Matthew MAcDonald

Comment: Matthew MAcDonald does not seem to be much of a pro, after all.

Comment: Or maybe I am not :-) I learned something thanks to GvS

Answer (score 5):

If you use cookieless sessions, then a session id is inserted into the url like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/12345/Default.aspx
```

Now if you link from default.aspx to: "http://www.mysite.com/dosomething.aspx" (`<a href="http://www.mysite.com/dosomething.aspx">...</a>`), the link with the session is lost. If you have used "dosomething.aspx" (`<a href="dosomething.aspx">...</a>`) as the link, the browser will resolve this to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/12345/dosomething.aspx
```

As you can see, the sessionid now is known to the server.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET uses a trick that parses the URL so that from the client's perspective it is in the same directory so it will always retain the session id without you having to worry about changing your javascript or external javascript files, etc.

Example:
http://localhost:50311/SomeWebSite/(S(f2rvdgj1bj1nyuzhfeqrvveq))/Page2.aspx

Normally the URL would be "http://localhost:50311/SomeWebSite/Page2.aspx" but since the web client (browser) thinks that the session id is a directory (/(S(f2rvdgj1bj1nyuzhfeqrvveq))/) it will happily try to stay in that same directory.

This way, ASP.NET does not have at actually reparse the urls outputted, the client automatically just forwards it.

If you want absolute URL's to gain the session ID, it should be trivial to create a special anchor control that verifies that the the target url is in the root of your application so you don't pass along that session id to an external application, which wouldn't know what to do with it.